# Connect motor control board's 4 terminals to brushed motor

Tags: motor-controller, magnetics, brushed-dc-motor

Although I have a degree in engineering, it's mechanical engineering. In addition, I have been developing software since I graduated, so please excuse my obvious ignorance about electronics hardware.

I need to connect the control board to the small circular board and/or connectors on top of the motor, or, perhaps, the motor casing?! I'd like to avoid another 3 month wait like the one which resulted from previously having shorted them out :-).  If anyone could help by explaining what the various thing are, I would be very grateful!

The motor is from a sea scooter, which is powered by a 24V lead-acid battery.  So, 24V DC into the board and 24V out. There are a couple of magnetic relays on the board, which control the following: one controls stop/go, while the other takes it from half to full speed. That's about as much as I can give :-(

Many thanks in advance, even if it's just a link to a page where I can inform myself.

[image: NTC required?]
[image: Brushed Motor]
[image: motor board]
[image: top of control board]
[image: Control Board]

[image: bottom old board]
[image]

Answer (score 1):

M+ and M- are the only ones that go to the motor tabs. Either way is fine; Just changes assigned direction of rotation. Doesn't look like anything else goes to the motor.

That PCB on the motor doesn't look like it does very much. Just noise supression measures it looks like. That wire on the motor can probably be ignored if you want. It looks like it is just a midpoint connection between the noise filtering caps so you could connect it to the case or chassis if you want.

Comment: That is reassuring, am I right in thinking that the NTC connector is for some sort of heat sensor on the motor, can you see where that shouod be connected...I wcouldn't see anything that jumped out.  Thnaks again for your help :-)

Comment: @hicklehoff Your motor probably doesn't have an NTC which means you can only really put it on the case.

Comment: The black component on the motor PCB may be a diode. This would mean that the manufacturer intended it to go only in one direction and you should not reverse the motor leads.

Comment: @ScienceGeyser True, but I ASSUMED it was a bidirectional TVS diode which would allow rotation in both directions. If it is a unidirectional diode then you are correct.

Comment: I think you're right,  it should only go one way, or things might get sucked into the prop  Thank you for looking, most grateful.

M+ to Motor +, M- To Motor -,Ground to the Motor casing and The wire on the small motor board to NTC for neatness or does that make no sense?

Comment: @DKNguyen I agree that this would be the most "likely" function of that component, but a careful examination of that would not hurt. That controller does not look like a full bridge controller to me, unless the components under the heatsink are two half bridges. The Trace routing on the PCB doesn't say that to me either.

Comment: @hicklehoff I would guess that the red wire is a ground and should go to the GND on your controller (though it is an admittedly strange wire color for grounding) . NTC would have likely gone where the R component is labeled but missing.

Comment: @ScienceGeyser I have added pictures of the old burnt out board that it replaced that hopefully gives a better idea as to what lies beneath and may help.  The old board is 5 pin but the new one uses an integrated buzzer negating the need for teh missing pin I think?

Comment: @ScienceGeyser On Closer inspection, I now understand what you mean about the missing R component, thank you. Forgive the flurry/brain dump.  Would you say it would be wise to buy one like this.  No idea how these are specified?

https://www.google.com/search?client=firefox-b-d&tbm=shop&q=ntc+component

Comment: @hicklehoff Does the old motor have the component? Maybe you can just reuse the old one or at least try to figure out the ratings.

Comment: @hicklehoff That must have been an exciting explosion.

Comment: @hicklehoff Looking at that rusty screw on the old board makes me wonder if there wasn't a leak. Do you run that thing in sea water? It doesn't take much salt to cause a lot of corrosion, so maybe the leak is so small it's hard to detect. It is possible that this was caused by repeated high heat, but I find it unlikely for a single short circuit event.

Comment: @ScienceGeyser  Ah yes definitely a sea water leak, I haven't shorted the board yet personally that was the seals leaking, it just took 3 months for the replacement to arrive from China. I have a vague memory of an NTC looking a little like the one I have just added in the main text.  With 24v and a 300W output and for example not wanting the temperature much above 70C or 80C I imagine there is a way of getting the right one?

Comment: The NTC image you posted looks more like an inrush current limiting device than a temperature sensing device. The NTCs that are typically used for temperature sensing will most often be in a small epoxy bead. The size of the NTC has nothing to do with the power of the motor. You are only using it to sense temperature, it is not in series with the load like an inrush current limiting device.

Comment: @ScienceGeyser Thank you so much for your time and knowledge!
Would it make electrical sense to place this in the marked yet empty position on the motor board and which side of the thermistor on which side on the board would you attach the thermistror; would you attach one side to the thermistor and  the other to the casing?

https://www.ebay.co.uk/itm/5pcs-NTC-10k-Thermistor-MF52-103-Temperature-Sensitive-Resistor/264908446152

Comment: I would use the NTC and ground pins to connect the NTC, but you should then isolate the filter network for the motor (red wire) noise and connect it elsewhere. Coupling motor noise to the NTC ground may cause unwanted behavior of the controller. Maybe there are some nearby metal structural components where you can attach that. Or just go on the motor metal like others have suggested. Position the NTC right up next to the motor and maybe even use some Kapton tape to stick it on.

Comment: @ScienceGeyser I followed all your advice but when the NTC I selected was in circuit the motor did not run.  When out of circuit it did...I suppose you can conclude that the room temperature resistence of the thermistor was insufficient and that any NTC should not reduce resistence to this components resistence until a high emp was reached?!

How are they labeled and rated and do you have any advice on selection please.

Good news is that everythign else worked...just one more piecce of the puzzle left!

Comment: You need to know two things to choose the right thermistor. What is the cutout resistance of the control circuit and what is the maximum allowable temperature on the motor. For the controller cutout resistance, you could use a resistor substitution. For the motor temp, you need at look at the motor design.

Comment: You could say, as an ultra conservative limit, that you don't want your motor to exceed 80 degrees Celsius. Most motors can tolerate a 40 degree increase from 40 degree ambient starting point. If you don't like the performance at that cutout temperature, increase it in 10 degree increments. Some motors ate rated up to 180 degrees Celsius, other should not exceed 80 degrees. You can get a 50% reduction in motor life for every 10 degrees above the rated temperature so it's worth figuring out the rating.